# Stambaugh Bias in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

I am trying to estimate a predictive model in R, in the spirit of Goyal and Welch (2008), such that:

$R_t = \alpha + \beta_1 X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

I am aware about the possibility of having Stambaugh bias. However, I do not know how to correct for it using bootstraping in R.

My OLS model is

```
lm(eval(parse(text=Rt)) ~ lag(eval(parse(text=DP)), -1), data=window(df, start, end))
```

Can someone who experienced this before tell me how to write a code to bootstrap this using 10,000 bootstrapped time series. Given that the DGP is:

$ y_{t+1} = \alpha + \beta x_t + u_{1,t+1}$

$ x_{t+1} = \mu + \rho x_t + u_{2,t+1} $

Comment: Are you following any textbook, lecture note or paper? Could you give the reference?

Comment: Goyal and Welch (2008) pages 1462 and 1463 mention how to overcome it. 
Also Rapach and Zhou Forecasting stock returns pages 337 and 338

Comment: Given these, do you have a conceptual question or do you need help with programming? In the former case, consider editing your post to make it more explicit and detailed.

Comment: My question is about how to estimate this in R.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for code is off topic.